# Can this upper vent be covered?

Tags: heating, fireplace, heat, fire

[image]

can this upper vent be covered/removed? This is a wood fireplace, that we plan on using. There is also a hole in the right side of the fireplace.

We plan on putting a large post/shelf where this vent is, but are unsure if covering or removing this is unsafe.

Comment: refer to the fireplace instalation instructions ...

Comment: At minimum it will reduce the effectiveness of the fireplace at producing heat, as it's all but certain to be the exhaust vent of a "heatilator" to recover some heat before it goes up the flue. Unless you are "using it" merely for amusement value rather than to get some heat, this plan sounds unwise for that reason alone. The location is probably also too close to the top of the fireplace for any shelf made of wood or other combustible materials.

Answer (score 0):

The comments have already addressed that you should look at the installation instructions of the fireplace. And it is probably an exhaust.  Ours needed in air inlet, but that was a grill much lower down.

Whether you remove the vent or not.  If you are wanting to put a timber shelf, you can do what we did.  We got a metal heat deflector made - it was actually designed by our fireplace installer.  It was very thin, barely visible, and hung down about an inch from the shelf.  It was very effective.